# How to populate DropDownButton by table names

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

In the project I have db01.accdb database
db01DataSet is created by Add New DataSource Wizard in vs 2010.

I'm trying to add items to a DdropDownButton

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (DataTable dt in db01DataSet.Tables) {
drop01.DropDownItems.Add(dt.TableName);
}}
```

Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to get table names from database : using this query

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name AS table_name FROM MSysObjects WHERE (((Left([Name],1))<>"~") 
    AND ((Left([Name],4))<>"MSys") 
    AND ((MSysObjects.Type) In (1,4,6))) order by MSysObjects.Name
```

this will give all MS access table names...

Comment: @Alegro I just excite same query  in my Northwind 2007.accdb database . I am able to retrieve all tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try TableName instead:

```
drop01.DropDownItems.Add(dt.TableName);
```

The current posted code won't produce anything though, since the DataSet was just created and doesn't have any tables in it.  If db01DataSet was created by the wizard, then you shouldn't be creating "new" one, just use the one provided.

Comment: @ Lars, third line. `db01DataSet.Tables` is red underlined

Comment: @Alegro You might have to not use that strongly typed dataset to do that.  Your db01DataSet has direct references to the tables and views you included when you created it through the wizard.